# Convert Functions into lambda functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have to convert the following functions into lambda functions, without changing the semantics. How i have to do this?

```
u = 1

def method1(x):
    def method2(n):
        def method3(m):
            return x + n + m
        def method4():
            global u
            u += 1
        method4()
        return method3
    def method5(y):
        return x + y
    return method2, method5
```

Edit:
Here are my attempts:

```
method1 x: method2 n: method3 m: x+n+m, method 4 (): method 3, method5 y: x+y, method2 method3
```

Edit2:

```
method1 = lambda x:
    method2 = lambda n:
        method3 = lambda m:
         x + n + m
        method4 = lambda :
         global u
         u = u + 1
        #dont know how to integrate "method4() return method3"
    method5 = lambda y:
      x + y
    method2, method5
```

Comment: 1) read about [lambdas](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions).

Comment: 2) show your attempts.

Comment: edited them above

Comment: Looks like you aren't really comfortable with `lambda` syntax...

Comment: These are not lambda expressions. Please return to the first point: 1) read about [lambdas](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions).

Comment: method4 if not possible to transform to lambdas. And why you want to do this?

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: You've not answered why you want this. And you tell us. Does that code run?

Comment: @cricket_007: they gave us the code in a lecture in university

Comment: Basically, you've not covered point 1 enough. Lambdas cannot be multiple lines, nor do I think you can define them within one another

Comment: Ok then i do not understand the explanation for lambdas at the docs for python.

Comment: Is this an exercise? If so, can you post the exact task you've been assigned? Either you misunderstood what was asked of you, or the lecturer likes to hand out impossible tasks.

Comment: The task is to convert as many "def" into lambdas as possible, without changing the semantics.

Comment: Ah, "as many as possible", not "all". There you go. (Figuring out which _are_ possible to convert _and which aren't_ is your task and part of the exercise.)

Comment: Note that by "as many as possible", the exercise author probably didn't mean "as many as you are able to with your skills" but rather "all for which it is possible in general", thus leaving those functions as traditional `def` functions for which it is positively impossible to convert them to lambdas.

Comment: so maybe i dont have to change the code? Otherwise i would say i just can change method3, method 4 and method 5?

Comment: @cricket_007 lambdas _can_ be nested. E.g. `(lambda x: lambda y: 2 * x + y)(4)(12)` evaluates to `20` and so does `(lambda x: (lambda y: 2 * x + y)(12))(4)`. But lambdas cannot contain arbitrary statements (like assignments etc.), only expressions. Thus the outer lambda cannot assign the inner lambda to any function name.

Comment: @das-g Sure, then we get into function currying, which is another topic

Comment: Why do you want to use lambdas? These methods are complex enough that making them lambdas would decrease the readability a ton. I can barely understand them as regular functions. Reading the lambdas was hell. You should try to keep these as regular functions.

Answer (score 6):

Python's `lambda`s are a lot more powerful than most people seem to think.

```
u = 1
(lambda x: (
    (lambda n: [
        (lambda m: x + n + m),
        (lambda: globals().__setitem__('u', globals()['u'] + 1))()
     ][0]),
    (lambda y: x + y)
))
```

Comment: Never seen this before. Impressive writing. Validated your code with python 3.6.7 with much success.